# Creating a Git branch based on a commit done by someone else

Tags: git, github

When trying to use git branch, I got "fatal: not a valid branch point".
I didn't find a way to do it remotely in GitHub.
So how can I do it?

Comment: What command are you trying to run?

Comment: git branch <branch-name> <SHA>

Comment: Funny question, but... Are you fetched (or pulled)?

Comment: Have you pulled the start commit from the remote repository?

Comment: Well, it's strange, because the local branch which I'm trying to branch from has just been created, based on the corresponding remote branch, so I assumed it has to include all the commits, but it seems it's actually based on a much previous commit, and I don't understand why... (sorry if I sound stupid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
git checkout -b <branch-name> <SHA>
```